# Reading boolean Variables from a File

Tags: java, file, boolean

The program I am currently working on is supposed to use input read in from a file to create a series of triangles. The information in the file is 3 sides of type double, color of type String, and filled of type boolean. It's this boolean variable that's giving me some issues.

In the file, the information is laid out like this:

```
1.0 1.5 1.0 yellow  T
3.0 4.0 5.0 blue F
```

Where T stands for True (yes the object is filled) and F stands for false (no the object is not filled), but I"m having some trouble getting the computer to recognize this. Right now I'm using a while loop to go through the code and assign each value to the corresponding variable like this:

```
while (fin.hasNext()) {
        double side1 = fin.nextDouble();
        double side2 = fin.nextDouble();
        double side3 = fin.nextDouble();
        String color = fin.next();
        boolean filled = fin.nextBoolean();
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3, color, filled);
        System.out.println(triangle);
    }
    fin.close();
```

but as this is written, I'm getting an InputMismatchException error at line 14 which is at the line:

```
boolean filled = fin.nextBoolean();
```

How would I write the filled variable in a way that would let the program know that T is true and F is false?

There is much more code for this particular program, but since this is where my problem is occurring at the moment, I thought it would be simpler to just post this portion of code. If it would help to have the entire code, let me know and I can add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problem:**

```
fin.nextBoolean();
```

It only accepts string "true" as true and "false" as false thus giving you `InputMismatchException`

**solution:**

Either change your file for T to "true" and T to "false"

***or***

read the `boolean` as `string` and use the `equals` method to check if it is true or false

```
 String bool = fin.next();
 boolean filled;
 if(bool.equals("T"))
      filled = true;
 else
      filled = false;
```

Comment: I figured it was something like that. Thanks!